# plotting sequence in timeline

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I googled a bit but could not find a good solution. I have a sequence of events: A, B and C occurring over time repeatedly and I want to plot this on a timeline somewhat as follows:

AAABBBBAAAAACCAAAAAAAAABBBBABBBBB

But in a more aesthetic and colorful way. I use gnuplot, so, if someone knows the trick with gnuplot, that would be great.

The format of raw data is as follows:

```
A   4
B   6
C  10
A  14
B  17
C  22
A  27
B  27
C  35
A  35
```

And the gnuplot script that I worked out is as follows:

```
set terminal png enhanced
set style data histograms

set style histogram columnstacked
set output "timeline.png"
set xlabel "events"
set ylabel "min"
set auto x
set xtics 1
set key top left
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
set style fill solid 0.6 border -1
plot 'timeline.txt' using 2 t "execution"
```

After running this script on above data, I get the following plot:
[image: Columnstacked histogram]

I want: 1) the colors to be repeating based on the letters on first column and 2) the histogram to be horizontal, one-dimension plot.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
sum=0
cum_sum(x)=(sum=sum+x,sum-x/2)
set yrange [-1:2]
set xrange [0:*]
unset ytics
set style fill solid
plot 'test.dat' using (cum_sum($2)):(1.0):($2):($0) w boxes t "execution" lc variable
```

and here's a version which colors the boxes based on the label (I have to admit, I'm pretty proud of this hack):

```
sum=0
cum_sum(x)=(sum=sum+x,sum-x/2)
set yrange [-1:2]
set xrange [0:*]
unset ytics
set style fill solid
LABELS="ABCD"
plot 'test.dat' using (cum_sum($2)):(1.0):($2):(strstrt(LABELS,strcol(1))) w boxes t "execution" lc variable
```

If you want to control which color a particular label gets, you'd want to use `set style line X lc rgb 'cyan'` where the label which starts at index `X` in the `LABELS` string will be colored `cyan`.

Comment: Thanks! I actually wanted to represent the labels with bars of the size corresponding to the time interval that event occurs. Pretty much like a horizontal stacked histogram.

Comment: Very much like shown in section "Kurdistan workers party" on this page: http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Plugins/EasyTimelinePlugin

Comment: I updated my question with more inputs. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Excellent! That works well for me. Thanks. I'll go ahead and accept your answer.